# in Play Framework 2.x How to mapping form parameter to different name object field?

Tags: forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

for example

Form class is

```
public class UserForm {
    public int userId;
}
```

and form mapping is like this

```
Form<UserForm> userForm = Form.form(UserForm.class).bindFromRequest();
```

but form parameter is "user_id". so mapping is not working.
I knew that **public int userId -> public int user_id** is working.
but I want to make that UserForm member variable name is "userId"

is possible to make custom parameter mapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java form data binding in Play is based on Spring databind, which is based on the Java beans API, and as far as I can see, neither of them support custom property names.